# Bash variable substitution and strings

Tags: bash, variables, substitution

Let's say I have two variables:

```
a="AAA"
b="BBB"
```

I read a string from a file. This string is the following:

```
str='$a $b'
```

How to create a new string from the first one that substitutes the variables?

```
newstr="AAA BBB"
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) variable *indirection* whithout `eval`:

Well, as `eval` is *evil*, we may try to make this whithout them, by using *indirection* in variable names.

```
 a="AAA"
 b="BBB"
 str='$a $b'

 newstr=()
 for cnt in $str ;do
     [ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt=${cnt:1} && cnt=${!cnt}
     newstr+=($cnt)
   done
 newstr="${newstr[*]}"

 echo $newstr
 AAA BBB
```

Another try:

```
var1="Hello"
var2="2015"

str='$var1 world! Happy new year $var2'

newstr=()
for cnt in $str ;do
    [ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt=${cnt:1} && cnt=${!cnt}
    newstr+=($cnt)
  done
newstr="${newstr[*]}"

echo $newstr 
Hello world! Happy new year 2015
```

**Addendum** As correctly pointed by @EtanReisner's comment, if your string do contain some `*` or other *glob* expendable stings, you may have to use `set -f` to prevent bad things:

```
cd /bin
var1="Hello"
var2="star"
var3="*"
str='$var1 this string contain a $var2 as $var3 *'

newstr=()
for cnt in $str ;do
     [ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt=${cnt:1} && cnt=${!cnt};
     newstr+=("$cnt");
   done;
newstr="${newstr[*]}"

echo "$newstr"
Hello this string contain a star as * bash bunzip2 busybox....zmore znew

echo ${#newstr}
1239
```

**Note:** I've added `"` at `newstr+=("$cnt");` to prevent glob expansion, but `set -f` seem required...

```
newstr=()
set -f
for cnt in $str ;do
    [ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt=${cnt:1} && cnt=${!cnt}
    newstr+=("$cnt")
  done
set +f
newstr="${newstr[*]}"

echo "$newstr"
Hello this string contain a star as * *
```

**Nota 2:** This is far away from a perfect solution. For sample if string do contain ponctuation, this won't work again... Example:

```
str='$var1, this string contain a $var2 as $var3: *'
```

with same variables as previous run will render:
`' this string contain a star as  *'` because `${!var1,}` and `${!var3:}` don't exist.

#### ... and if `$str` do contain special chars:

As [@godblessfq](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2687597/godblessfq) asked:

> If str contains a line break, how do I do the substitution and preserve the newline in the output?

So this is not *robust* as *every indirected variable **must** be first, last or **space separated** from all special chars!*

```
str=$'$var1 world!\n... 2nd line...'
var1=Hello
newstr=()
set -f
IFS=' ' read -d$'\377' -ra array <<<"$str"
for cnt in "${array[@]}";do
    [ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt=${cnt:1} && cnt=${!cnt}
    newstr+=("$cnt")
  done
set +f
newstr="${newstr[*]}"

echo "$newstr"
Hello world!
... 2nd line...
```

As `<<<` inline string add a trailing newline, last `echo` command could be written:

```
echo "${newstr%$'\n'}"
```

Comment: You may later need to implement things like `${var}` etc., but nice.

Comment: This is a very nice way to handle it by using the `${!var}` indirection. Well done!

Comment: This expands globs if they occur in the string. You'd want to use `set -f` to prevent that. It also acts like `tr -s ' '` on the input string which may be important. It also is assigning the full string to `n[0]` and not changing `n` from an array to a string variable (though this doesn't really matter at all).

Comment: @EtanReisner You'r right, but there is a lot of other *bugs*, like the fact that source string can't have ponctuation in it: `$var1: $var=$var3` won't work... This have to be adapted in regard to specific requirements... Anyway, I've added a note about `set -f`.

Comment: Oh, sure that was *far* from comprehensive advice. It just pointed out a few of the problems with this solution. You pointed some other quite relevant ones. But those are "algorithm" details and not implementation ones. And yes, you need both `set -f` and the quotes in `("$cnt")` to prevent pathname expansion at both points.

Comment: If str contains a line break, how do I do the substitution and preserve the newline in the output?

Comment: @godblessfq Replace `for` line by: `IFS=' ' read -d$'\377' -ra array <<<"$str";for cnt in "${array[@]}";do`

Comment: No, it doesn't preserve the newline. The answer on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39739673/how-to-expand-bash-variable-in-a-string-and-preserve-newline?noredirect=1#comment66792214_39739673 works.

Comment: @godblessfq Yes it do! See the last part of my answer, I've edited after your comment!

Answer (score 4):

The easiest solution is to use `eval`:

```
eval echo "$str"
```

To assign it to a variable, use command substitution:

```
replaced=$(eval echo "$str")
```

Comment: This is perfect. But I think it could be risky from a security standpoint so I'll be careful.

Comment: @mimipc: If you control `$str`, nothing bad should happen even if `$a` and `$b` were wild.

Comment: Interesting reading: [Eval command and security issues](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/048)

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: I only discovered `perl` an hour ago. But this seems to work robustly, whatever special characters you throw at it:

```
newstr=$(a2="$a" b2="$b" perl -pe 's/\$a\b/$ENV{a2}/g; s/\$b\b/$ENV{b2}/g' <(echo -e "$str"))
```

Test:

```
a='A*A\nA'
b='B*B\nB'
str='$a $aa * \n $b $bb'

newstr=$(a2="$a" b2="$b" perl -pe 's/\$a\b/$ENV{a2}/g; s/\$b\b/$ENV{b2}/g' <(echo -e "$str"))

echo -e "$newstr"
```

Output:

```
A*A
A $aa * 
 B*B
B $bb
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd use awk solution with awk-variables. This will allow passing a text containing special chars and subsitute any placeholder with it.
a workaround to recognize $ would be using [\x24]:

```
awk -v a="$a" -v b="$b" '{gsub("[\x24]a",a);gsub("[\x24]b",b); print}' <<< $str
```

here

- `-v` defines variable a="$a"
- `[x24]` is ASCII for $, so [x24]a equal to $a
- `gsub(x,y)` - replaces x with y