# How to expand bash variable in a string and preserve newline

Tags: bash, sh

This one works for single line string:

```
var2="2018"
str="${var1:-hello} world! 
Happy $var2 new year $var2"

newstr=()
for cnt in "$str" ;do
    echo "$cnt"
    [ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt=${cnt:1} && cnt=${!cnt}
    newstr+=($cnt)
done
newstr="${newstr[*]}"
```

How to preserve the newline?

Comment: What is your input and expected output?

Comment: this could be help; http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27423/how-to-discover-a-new-line-using-a-for-loop

Comment: Your initial premise, that parameters make a good basis for a templating system, is faulty.

Comment: I am trying to set the default value for var1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if I fail to fully understand what your goal is,
correctly quoting will preserve the new lines.

Change this two lines:

```
[ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt="${cnt:1}" && cnt="${!cnt}"
newstr+=("$cnt")
```

Comment: It works. I am trying to modify the cheat package on https://github.com/lucaswerkmeister/cheats, my version (https://gist.github.com/QiangF/565102ba3b6123942b9bf6b897c05f87) will allow multiline command. However, I am still need to get the default value for a variable to work.

Answer (score 0):

The purpose of the script is obscure to me, but here is the way I would write it to read line by line:

```
var2="2018"
str="${var1:-hello} world! 
Happy $var2 new year $var2"

newstr=()
while read cnt; do
    echo "$cnt"
    [ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt=${cnt:1} && cnt=${!cnt}
    newstr+=($cnt)
done < <(echo "$str")
newstr="${newstr[*]}"
```

The `read` command reads one line after the other. The natural way to write it would be with a pipe:

```
var2="2018"
str="${var1:-hello} world! 
Happy $var2 new year $var2"

newstr=()
echo "$str" | while read cnt; do
    echo "$cnt"
    [ "${cnt:0:1}" == '$' ] && cnt=${cnt:1} && cnt=${!cnt}
    newstr+=($cnt)
done
newstr="${newstr[*]}"
```

However the pipe creates a subshell and the variables modified inside the `while` loop would be discarded once stepping out of it, here especially the `newstr` variable.

Comment: Your method doesn't preserve the newline.